# Can't connect to admin console using Virtualbox

Tags: windows, jboss, virtualbox, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have a VirtualBox debian VM with wildfly running. The host is a Windows 8.1. I have forwarded ports 8080 and 9990.

I have edited the standalone.xml to include:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

As expected, I can access the webservice(s) on `http://localhost:8080/webservice` from the host as well as the admin console on `http://localhost:9990/`.

So far so good, but when I run the same virtual machine image on another PC using Windows 7, I can only access the webservice but not the admin console.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there not another (perhaps windows) service running on that port?

Try to run `netstat -a -b` from the command line to find out.

[TCPview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) is another great tool you could use.

Comment: Brilliant, that was it - I would never have thought about that.