# WildFly: can't open administration panel on windows

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-8

I started WildFly 8.2. And can open `http://localhost:8080/`

Btw, on Ubuntu it was different port.

Anyway, I cant open `localhost:8080/console` or `http://127.0.0.1:9990/console`. Just nothing happen. I make same steps like on ubuntu. But on Win 7 I cant open admin page.

In console after start i see:

> 00:19:46,011 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service
>   thread 1-3) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on
>   /127.0.0.1:8080

And...

> 00:19:46,344 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951:
>   Admin console listening on `http://127.0.0.1:9990`

What should i do?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960487/cant-connect-to-admin-console-using-virtualbox - make sure the 9990 port is not used by another application.

Comment: @assylias hm, i thougth that if port was used i see it in cosole after start...But ok, after i change port in standalone.xml it works fine. Tnx anyway )

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar issue and it turns out that we tried to open admin console from IE8, which is the only browser was available on the server at the time. Looks like Wildfly 8.2 does not support IE8, which is make sense. Issue solved by using different browser.

Answer (score 0):

Very often (in my practice) it happens because of one or both of the ports 8080 and 9990 are in use by other [java] processes.
Admin console is listening on port 9990, but it doesn't guarantee something else doesn't use it.

You can also use `netstat -noa | find "port number"` and then `tasklist | findstr PID_of_process` to check which process uses your ports.

To change port modify `standalone.xml`.